# Port not opening

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to enable postgres externally, but for some reason, enabling port 5432 on google cloud engine doesn't work.

[image]
[image]

I've tried with other ports such as 8080 for Apache, and that works fine. Is there an additional setting that is required? or default rule that is blocking the port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firewall rule you include looks ok. What remains to be checked is whether you have the right IP, and whether port 5432 is open on the destination IP. This can be accomplished remotely with this command

$ sudo nmap -sS [IP]

or on the VM itself with

$ netstat -a --numeric-ports | grep 5432

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10646    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

Comment: for nmap, I get PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Comment: also tried opening port 3300, seems like its not applying

Comment: From your output it looks like your Postgres is listening on the loopback device (IP 127.0.0.1), but not any other. This can be changed by editting Postgresql's config file (/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf, for instance), setting listen_addresses to '*'. After a save, and service restart (sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart) your database server ought to be listening on the eth0 IP as well, including the external, one-to-one NATed address.